# Proof of Test of primality from E.Dickson's book "History of theory of numbers vol.1"

Tags: trigonometry, prime-numbers, primality-test

E.Dickson mentioned the following result by E.Zondadari in his book "History of theory of numbers vol.1"(Chap XVIII):

Consider the following 'function':

$$ \frac{\sin²(πx)}{(πx)²(1-x²)^2} \prod_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(πx)} {n\sin(πx/n)}  $$

It's zero if |x|= prime and else otherwise .

> > How to prove the above identity ?

Comment: Is $x$ real or complex?

Comment: @saulspatz real

Comment: I don't understand.  If $x=4$ say, then the factor outside the product is $0$ so if the product converges, the value must be $0$.  What am I missing?

Comment: @saulspatz the doubt is mutual ; that's why ,earlier ,I added the image of the page of the book in the first place . But got downvotes saying don't add images!

Comment: if n divides x we get a division by 0 under my interprwtation. but it still fails for primes then unless it's an empty product.

Comment: [Here's the original](https://archive.org/details/historyoftheoryo01dick/page/428/mode/2up). I don't see any image in previous versions of this post, nor any downvotes. There's no reason not to add an image (unless it's copyrighted); it's just that you shouldn't *only* post an image. By the way, don't use the superscript ² character instead of `^2`; as you can see it messes up the formatting.

Comment: @saulspatz: For $x=4$ the expression is undefined because one of the denominators vanishes. I think it's meant to be interpreted as a limit when $x$ is an integer. The idea is that for $x$ prime only one denominator is zero, whereas the numerator has two zero factors, so the limit is $0$, whereas for $x$ composite at least two denominators are zero so the limit is finite.

Comment: @joriki I deleted the original post and started from  new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A copy of Zondadari's paper can be found [here](https://archive.org/details/rendiconti51911910acca/page/318/mode/1up/search/Zondadari).

The key to understanding the stated result is an earlier one that the infinite product
$$
P(x)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin\frac{\pi x}{n}}{\frac{\pi x}{n}}
$$
converges absolutely and uniformly to an analytic function whose zeros are precisely the non-zero integers, with multiplicities equal to the number of their positive divisors. By $\ \frac{\sin\frac{\pi x}{n}}{\frac{\pi x}{n}}\ $ Zondadari obviously here means the analytic function 
$\ \sum_\limits{i=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^i}{(2i+1)!}\left(\frac{\pi x}{n}\right)^{2i}\ $, which assumes the value $1$ at $\ x=0\ $, and adopts the convention that an infinite product with only a finite number of zeroes and a tail that converges to a non-zero quantity is convergent.

Enumerating the zeros of this product, we have $\ \pm 1\ $, each of multiplicity $1$, primes (positive or negative), each of multiplicity $2$, and and composites, each of multiplicity $\ d\ $, where $\ d\  $ is the number of its positive divisors (equal to $\ \left(n_1+1\right) \left(n_2+1\right)\dots \left(n_r+1\right)\ $, where $\ p_1^{n_1}p_2^{n_2}\dots p_r^{n_r}\ $ is its prime decomposition).

Now the function
$$
f(x) =\frac{\sin^3\pi x}{(\pi x)^3\left(1-x^2\right)^2}
$$
has zeros of multiplicty $3$ at every integer, except $0$, where it has value $1$, and $\ \pm1\ $, where it has zeros of multiplicity $1$.  Therefore, the function
\begin{align}
g(x)&= \frac{\sin^3\pi x}{(\pi x)^3\left(1-x^2\right)^2}\cdot\frac{1}{P(x)}\\
&= \frac{\sin^2\pi x}{(\pi x)^2\left(1-x^2\right)^2} \prod_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\pi x}{n\sin\frac{\pi x}{n}}
\end{align}
has zeros of multiplictity $1$ for prime $\ x\ $, a pole of multiplicity $\ d-3\ $ at any composite $\ x\ $ with $\ d\ $ positive divisors, and has a finite non-zero value at $\ x=0\ $ and $\ x=\pm1\ $.

Comment: thank you for the answer . Also , I'm asking if the product could be twisted in such a way that it gives zero for primes and finite values for composite ?

Comment: The function $\ \frac{g(x)}{g(x)+x}\ $ will vanish for prime $\ x\ $ and have value $1$ for composite $\ x\ $.

Comment: Is this a  "good" test ?( Efficiency)

Comment: @lonzaleggiera: I see, sorry, I hadn't reloaded; I've deleted the comment.

Comment: I can't claim any expertise in tests for primality, but it looks to me that to distinguish whether an integer  $\ x\ne\pm1, 0\ $ is a zero or a pole of  $\ g(x)\ $  you would need to evaluate  $\ \sin\frac{\pi x}{n}\ $ at least for  $\ n= 2, 3,\dots,\left\lfloor\sqrt{|x|}\right\rfloor\ $, which would be even less efficient than using trial division as a test for primality.